# Differences between equal sign(=) and IN with subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query it takes 20 seconds to execute, follow my query:

```
SELECT MATLIGA.COD_MAT_FAMILIA 
FROM 
    ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_1INSUMOS INSUMOS
    INNER JOIN ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_MAT_GRUPOS GRUPOS ON (GRUPOS.EMPRESA='01' AND GRUPOS.FILIAL='01' AND GRUPOS.CODIGO_INTERNO = 'HOT' )
    INNER JOIN ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_MATERIAIS MATER ON (MATER.EMPRESA='01' AND MATER.FILIAL='01' AND MATER.CODIGO_GRUPO=GRUPOS.ID AND MATER.ID = INSUMOS.COD_INSUMO_MATER )
    INNER JOIN ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_MAT_LIGACAO MATLIGA ON (MATLIGA.EMPRESA='01' AND MATLIGA.FILIAL='01' AND MATLIGA.CODIGO_MATERIAL  = INSUMOS.COD_INSUMO_MATER)
WHERE INSUMOS.EMPRESA='01' AND INSUMOS.FILIAL='01' 
AND INSUMOS.COD_INSUMO_MATER IS NOT NULL 
AND INSUMOS.NUMERO=10865812 
AND INSUMOS.OPCAO_SIMULACAO=1 
AND INSUMOS.CODIGO_MAQUINA = (SELECT COD_MAQ_PROPOSTA FROM ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_1SIMULACOES AS ORC WHERE  ORC.NUMERO=10865812 AND ORC.OPCAO_SIMULACAO = 1 AND ORC.EMPRESA='01' AND ORC.FILIAL='01' )  
AND INSUMOS.OPCAO_MAQUINA = (SELECT OPCAO_MAQUINA FROM ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_1SIMULACOES AS ORC WHERE  ORC.NUMERO=10865812 AND ORC.OPCAO_SIMULACAO = 1  AND ORC.EMPRESA='01' AND ORC.FILIAL='01' )  
GROUP BY MATLIGA.COD_MAT_FAMILIA  
ORDER BY  1
```

In these two lines bellow, if I change the equal signal by (IN), ( = ALL ) or ( = ANY ) it reduces the costs to 1 second.

```
AND INSUMOS.CODIGO_MAQUINA IN (SELECT COD_MAQ_PROPOSTA FROM ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_1SIMULACOES AS ORC WHERE  ORC.NUMERO=10865812 AND ORC.OPCAO_SIMULACAO = 1 AND ORC.EMPRESA='01' AND ORC.FILIAL='01' )  
AND INSUMOS.OPCAO_MAQUINA IN (SELECT OPCAO_MAQUINA FROM ORCAMENTOS.dbo.OR_1SIMULACOES AS ORC WHERE  ORC.NUMERO=10865812 AND ORC.OPCAO_SIMULACAO = 1  AND ORC.EMPRESA='01' AND ORC.FILIAL='01' )
```

Whats the difference between them?

Tks.

Comment: What do the execution plans show ?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan digrams to see the differences between the teo versions of the query?  The obvious logical difference is that the 'IN' can accept more than one result to compare against where the '=' forces the sub-query to only return one result.  Not sure what the means in terms of an execution difference.

Comment: It probably means SQL has to check the subquery only returns 1 row, with no such check required for `IN`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a small semantic difference.  The first query must fail if the subquery matches more than one record.  So it has to finish the subquery until the end:

```
where col1 = (select col1 from table2)
```

The second query can stop once it encounters a match:

```
where col1 in (select col1 from table2)
```