# SQL Difference between using = and IN

Tags: sql, oracle

Whats the difference between using the following statements in a WHERE clause in SQL?

```
WHERE STUDENTID=7
```

or

```
WHERE STUDENTID IN (7)
```

Is there a recommended/optimal choice?

Comment: `In` is for a list of items, `=` is for equality between something on the left and a single thing on the right.  As written, there is no difference.

Comment: In this specific case there is no difference whatsoever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741582/differences-between-equal-sign-and-in-with-subquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use IN if you're doing multiple or's e.g.

```
Where StudentID = 7 or StudentID = 6 or StudentID = 5
```

Would be

```
Where StudentID IN (5,6,7)
```

Otherwise just use =

Comment: Optimizer would anyway consider it as multiple `OR` conditions. The `IN` is just for an ease to code.

Answer (score 5):

There is no functional difference, the result is the same.

Performance would differ if the database treated them differently, but likely the database will recognise that you are using exactly one value in the `in` expression, and actually make the execution plan as if it was the first one.

You might want to use the first one either way, that makes it clearer that you intended to make an exact comparison, and didn't just forget to put the other values in the `in` expression.

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` operator is just a syntax sugar for:

```
( StudentID = 7 or StudentID = 6 or ... )
```

Therefore it handles NULL values the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from all other answers regarding the functional similarity etc, the important thing to note here is, no matter how you write the SQL, Oracle **OPTIMIZER** is smart enough to do a **query re-write** to chose the most **efficient execution plan**. The best way is to trace both the queries and see what's actually going under the hood. And you would find that the Optimizer does the query re-write as and when required to use an optimal execution plan.

As shown in one of the answers to use **IN** in case of multiple **OR** conditions -

> Where StudentID = 7 or StudentID = 6 or StudentID = 5

Optimizer would anyway consider it as multiple **OR** conditions, it is just for the ease to code using **IN**.

Answer (score 1):

If you use one value there are no differences. But if you use more than one you should use `IN` statement.

ex:

you want to take a,b and c values in your table.

if you want to use `=`, you should use like this;

```
Select * from table_name where name = 'a' or name = 'b' or name = 'c'
```

but if you use `IN`

```
Select * from table_name where name in('a','b','c')
```